# How to integrate a password-protected WMS layer into an OpenLayers GIS website without entering a separate password?

Tags: qgis, openlayers, qgis-plugins, wms, qgis2web

I'm building a small intranet site to display geodata easily. Using QGIS (2.18) and QGIS2WEB (2.34.0) I prepared geodata and created it as OpenLayers output as index.html.

A WMS layer, which is protected by username and password, is also part of the output. At the moment, however, an input mask opens, which asks for the username and password. After input, everything works correctly. But I don't want the users of the intranet site to have to enter a username or password.

Unfortunately, the following the proposal, circulating here in the forum, does not work. The input mask still appears.

http://**user:password**@geoinfo.xxx.de/wms10/72_sd_17_ds_gras.exe

There is no need to hide the data. They can be in the source text.

Is there another way to insert username and password '**automatically**'?

Comment: It is extremely bad security practice to send passwords in the clear on an HTTP link. If the service is password protected, you should honor that intention, or convince the provider to remove the password from internal addresses.

Comment: I agree in principle, but this is irrelevant in this particular case.

Comment: Could you cascade the WMS layer though another WMS server

Comment: Unfortunately, this is not possible.